# Find the determinant using colum or row operations

Tags: determinant

I find problem in simplification. When I tried to simplify I ended up doing the regular process of finding the determinant value. The matrix is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ a & b & c \\ ab & bc & ca \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Format using mathJax

Comment: You need to find a determinant. Then you learn that you end up "doing the regular process of finding the determinant value". I don't see any issues here.

Comment: What makes you think there is a way to find the determinant that's any simpler than "the regular process"?

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the first column from the other two, to get $\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ a & b-a & c-a \\ ab & bc - ab & ca - ab \end{vmatrix}$. Now compute the determinant, developing it along the first row, and obtain $\begin{vmatrix} b-a & c-a \\ bc-ab & ca-ab \end{vmatrix}$. This can further be calculated (with the usual formula for $2\times2$ determinants) to get $a(b-a)(c-b) - b(c-a)^2$, which you can't simplify anymore.

Comment: Dear @Majid, please stop vandalizing my answer. Both your edit attempts got rejected, please stop trying to push them through. Also, it is considered rude to change the formatting that some other user chose to use simply because you would have done it differently.

Answer (score 1):

What about computing the determinant directly based on the first row?

$$\det\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&1&1\\a&b&c\\ab&bc&ca\end {array}\right)=(bca-bc^2)-(ca^2-abc)+(abc-ab^2)=3abc-bc^2-ca^2-ab^2$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\det\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&1&1\\a&b&c\\ab&bc&ca\end {array}\right)=abc\det\left(\begin{array}{ccc}\frac{1}{a}&\frac{1}{b}&\frac{1}{c}\\1&1&1\\b&c&a\end {array}\right)=abc\det\left(\begin{array}{ccc}\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}&\frac{1}{b}&\frac{1}{c}-\frac{1}{b}\\0&1&0\\b-c&c&a-c\end {array}\right)=$$ 
$$abc\det\left(\begin{array}{ccc}\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}&\frac{1}{c}-\frac{1}{b}\\b-c&a-c\end {array}\right)=c(b-a)(a-c)-a(b-c)^{2}$$

Comment: No, what you get is (pay attention to the first row) $abc \det \begin{pmatrix} \frac 1 a & \frac 1 b & \frac 1 c \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ b & c & a \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: wait aminute, you can't factorize a term for a column???????

Comment: @juliogodoy: When you factorize by $a$, you must divide *all* the elements of that column by $a$. In particular, you must also divide $1$ by $a$, getting $\frac 1 a$.

Comment: @AlexM. you right

Comment: sorry i make mistake

Comment: i fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's unlikely that you would have learned of this method, but via [Dodgson condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodgson_condensation), you can reduce this to a problem of computing the determinants of several $2\times2$ matrices, which you might find easier to compute strictly via row operations.
$$\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1\\a&b&c\\ab&bc&ca\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}\dfrac{\begin{vmatrix}1&1\\a&b\end{vmatrix}}{b}&\dfrac{\begin{vmatrix}1&1\\b&c\end{vmatrix}}{b}\\[1ex]
\dfrac{\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\ab&bc\end{vmatrix}}{b}&\dfrac{\begin{vmatrix}b&c\\bc&ca\end{vmatrix}}{b}
\end{vmatrix}$$
The first determinant (in the $(1,1)$ position), for instance, would be
$$\begin{vmatrix}1&1\\a&b\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}1&1\\0&b-a\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}1&0\\0&b-a\end{vmatrix}=(b-a)\begin{vmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{vmatrix}=b-a$$